# Tkinter only works for one button press and not the others?

Tags: python, tkinter, serial-port, arduino

I am using a Tkinter window to pass information over the serial port to an arduino that turns a stepper motor a certain number of steps. Basically I have buttons that correspond to the number of steps that i want the motor to take. When I press the buttons I want the motor to move that many steps. Ill post some snippets of my code BUT Basically my problem is that the window works beautifully for the first button press but then when I click other buttons to get the motor to keep moving I don't get anything. It almost seems like the Tkinter window only works for one click or gets stuck in the callback function or something.

The Callback Functions:

```
def firstGrating():
    arduino.write('1800')
    tkMessageBox.showwarning(title= 'Spectrometer', message = 'I am moving to the 1800 Grating...')
    tkMessageBox.showwarning(title= 'Spectrometer', message = 'Please Wait Until I Tell You That I AM FINISHED!!!')
    while True:
        message = arduino.readline()
        if len(message) > 10:
            tkMessageBox.showwarning(title= 'Spectrometer', message = message)
    return

def secondGrating():
    arduino.write('150')
    tkMessageBox.showwarning(title= 'Spectrometer', message = 'I am moving to the 150 Grating...')
    tkMessageBox.showwarning(title= 'Spectrometer', message = 'Please Wait Until I Tell You That I AM FINISHED!!!')
    while True:
        message = arduino.readline()
        if len(message) > 10:
            tkMessageBox.showwarning(title= 'Spectrometer', message = message)
    return

def thirdGrating():
    arduino.write('3600')
    tkMessageBox.showwarning(title= 'Spectrometer', message = 'I am moving to the 3600 Grating...')
    tkMessageBox.showwarning(title= 'Spectrometer', message = 'Please Wait Until I Tell You That I AM FINISHED!!!')
    while True:
        message = arduino.readline()
        if len(message) > 10:
            tkMessageBox.showwarning(title= 'Spectrometer', message = message)
    return
```

and this is the part where I try to setup my Tkinter window:

```
win = Tk()
win.geometry("600x400+500+500")
win.title('Spectrometer Controller')

mlabel = Label(text = 'Select One of The Available Gratings')
mlabel.pack()

mButton1 = Button(win, text = '1800', command = lambda: firstGrating())
mButton1.pack()#.grid(row=0, column=1)
mButton2 = Button(win, text = '150', command = lambda: secondGrating())
mButton2.pack()#.grid(row=0, column=2)
mButton3 = Button(win, text = '3600', command = lambda: thirdGrating())
mButton3.pack()#.grid(row=0, column=3)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's getting stuck in the callback. `Tkinter`'s `mainloop()` creates a conflict with a `while` loop and becomes unresponsive, so there's no way to press another button while the `while` loop is running.

You can look at the [`after()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method to create a programmatic loop that will keep your GUI responsive. Here's an example:

```
def callback(flag):
    global loop
    if flag is True:
        print('message')
        ... other logic ...
        # start the after method to call the callback every 100ms
        loop = root.after(100, callback, True)
    else:
        # cancel the after method if the flag is False
        root.after_cancel(loop)

root = Tk()

# use a lambda expression to pass arg to callback in button commands
Button(root, text='start', command=lambda: callback(True)).pack()
Button(root, text='stop', command=lambda: callback(False)).pack()

mainloop()
```

You can also keep the GUI and the business in separate threads, but that's usually a PITA to set up. The `after()` method is usually just as effective.